# Using sp_flush_CT_internal_table_on_demand did not flush the records

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I just recently installed SQL Server 2012 sp4 to fix and add `sp_flush_CT_internal_table_on_demand`. Currently, my autoclean up with retention period of 5minutes is not cleaning up my side tables and `sys_committable` table. I've waited a couple of hours and it is still not working.

Even when I ran the stored procedure `sp_flush_CT_internal_table_on_demand` and `sys.sp_flush_commit_table_on_demand` manually, it still did not flush the records.

Any ideas how to flush the records?

```
exec sys.sp_flush_CT_internal_table_on_demand 'CT_Table'
exec sys.sp_flush_commit_table_on_demand 1000
```

Result for `sys.sp_flush_CT_internal_table_on_demand`:

```
Cleanup Watermark = 247171
Internal Change Tracking table name : change_tracking_168413161
Total rows deleted: 0.
Completion time: 2020-07-17T19:53:16.8926321-07:00
```

Result for `sys.sp_flush_CT_internal_table_on_demand`:

```
(0 rows affected)  
The Change Tracking manual cleanup procedure for database CEI has been executed  
Completion time: 2020-07-17T19:59:56.2205997-07:00
```

Comment: I assume that you are the same user who asked the question at the MSDN forums. If so, then I wrote you long explanation and some options. If you are not the same user then let's start with providing more information. Please collect the return information from the extended event session with event "change_tracking_cleanup" (at the time that you execute sp_flush_commit_table_on_demand). This should provide more information if the execution of sp_flush_commit_table_on_demand succeed or not and if not then why not. **Unfortunately in this poor interface I cannot write more then first point...**

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem today.  Originally I thought it must be the default change_retention of 2 days was in the way.  However, even when it was set to 1 minutes, the stored function still did not remove any rows from the internal change tracking tables.

I am not sure if I have contributed to this discussion or confused it further.  But thought put it out there for whoever run into similar issues or had a solution...

Answer (score 0):

Same issue for me.

SOLUTION: I had to issue a checkpoint on the database before the manual process would delete rows, in batches of 5000.